# Как присвоить свойство одного объекта другому. Объекты с одинаковыми типами

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть 2 объекта с одинаковыми типами. Один объект(назовем "fulledObj") изначально заполнен и в нем ведется перебор по ключам. Все найденные свойства необходимо при итерации записывать в другой объект(назовем "needfulProps"). Сразу скажу, что решение присваивания одного объекта другому/клонирование - не подходит. Мне нужна перезапись/создание свойства в объекте needfulProps.

*Комментарием в коде помечены нерабочие участки:

```
                    type responsiveArguments = {
                        heightRow?: string,
                        widthColumn?: string,
                        countColumns?: number,
                        countRows?: number,
                        rowGap?: number
                    }
                    let needfulResponsiveProps: responsiveArguments = {};
                    let oneWidthResponsiveObj: responsiveArguments = {
                        heightRow: "300px",
                        widthColumn: "500px",
                        countRows: 2
                    }
                    for (const keyResponsiveObj of Object.keys(oneWidthResponsiveObj) as (keyof responsiveArguments)[]) {
                        // Вывести в консоль объект с этим свойством я могу
                        console.log(`needfulResponsiveProps[keyResponsiveObj]: `,  needfulResponsiveProps[keyResponsiveObj]);
                        // Присвоить не могу
                        // Тип "string | number | undefined" не может быть назначен для типа "undefined". Тип "string" не может быть назначен для типа "undefined"
                        needfulResponsiveProps[keyResponsiveObj] = oneWidthResponsiveObj[keyResponsiveObj];
                    }
```

При этом если все поля в типе объекта одного типа - все работает верно:

```
                    type exampleType = { //все поля одного типа(number)
                        num?: number,
                        num2?: number
                    }

                    const filledObj: exampleType = {
                        num: 10,
                        num2: 15
                    }
                    let testConst: exampleType = {};
                    for (const key of Object.keys(filledObj) as (keyof exampleType)[]) {
                        testConst[key] = filledObj[key];
                    }
```

Полный код, из которого становится понятно, почему неуместно простое копирование объекта:

```
type responsive = {
            [resolution: number]: responsiveArguments;
        }
        type responsiveArguments = {
            heightRow?: string | undefined;
            widthColumn?: string | undefined;
            countColumns?: number | undefined;
            countRows?: number | undefined;
            rowGap?: number | undefined;
        }        
        /* for test */viewWidthDevice = 1500; // ширина устройства - будет считаться автоматически
        /* for test */responsive = {
            500: {
                countColumns: 500,
                countRows: 2
            },
            800: {
                countRows: 50,
                heightRow: "500px"
            },
            1900: {
                countColumns: 50
            }
        }
        
        let objPropsLessWidth: responsive = {};
        if(responsive) {
            for(let i = 0; i < viewWidthDevice; i++) {
                if(responsive.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    objPropsLessWidth[i] = responsive[i];
                };
            }
            console.log("objPropsLessWidth: ", objPropsLessWidth); //ключ 1900 будет убран, ведь ширин

            if(Object.keys(objPropsLessWidth).length > 0) {
                let needfulResponsiveProps: responsiveArguments = {};

                for (const keyOneResponsiveWidth in objPropsLessWidth) { // enumeration all responsive appropriate properties  
                    const oneWidthResponsiveObj: responsiveArguments = objPropsLessWidth[keyOneResponsiveWidth];
                    
                    //надо так:
                    for (const keyResponsiveObj of Object.keys(oneWidthResponsiveObj) as (keyof responsiveArguments)[]) {
                        //в левом операнде ошибка
                        //Тип "string | number | undefined" не может быть назначен для типа "undefined". Тип "string" не может быть назначен для типа "undefined".
                        needfulResponsiveProps[keyResponsiveObj] = oneWidthResponsiveObj[keyResponsiveObj];
                    }

                    //хочу избавиться от этого промежутка кода в сторону цикла, который выше
                    if(oneWidthResponsiveObj.countColumns) needfulResponsiveProps.countColumns = oneWidthResponsiveObj.countColumns;
                    if(oneWidthResponsiveObj.countRows) needfulResponsiveProps.countRows = oneWidthResponsiveObj.countRows;
                    if(oneWidthResponsiveObj.heightRow) needfulResponsiveProps.heightRow = oneWidthResponsiveObj.heightRow;
                    if(oneWidthResponsiveObj.rowGap) needfulResponsiveProps.rowGap = oneWidthResponsiveObj.rowGap;
                    if(oneWidthResponsiveObj.widthColumn) needfulResponsiveProps.widthColumn = oneWidthResponsiveObj.widthColumn;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Я так и не понял что Вам мешает написать needfulResponsiveProps = {...needfulResponsiveProps, ...oneWidthResponsiveObj } ?

Comment: Дело в том, что я делаю плагин, там будет опционально добавляться свойство responsive, в котором в свою очередь будет перебор всех требований....
Пока писал понял, что легче добавить код в шапку проблемы)
Пару минут

Comment: добавил код, должен внести больше ясности

Comment: стоп, а ведь правда...
Я что-то и не подумал о таком решении

Comment: ваш ответ является решением моей проблемы - оформите его, пожалуйста, отдельным ответом, чтобы я смог это указать

Comment: Ну почему надо писать такой длиннющий вопрос, когда код упрощается до [вот такого](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFswAtkG8BQyyAHgFzIDOYUoA5ocgJ7kgCu6ARtPgL774ATCAgA2cKCgBu45HHIZs-GAHsoyABQJlIKsgDWERsmUxkAeQ4ArYWAB0BxhXVwAlLIoaHJtJiwuA2gC6bgREcP4OgcgAvLIRhoG8+EA) ну или (на всякий случай) [такого](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFswAtkG8BQyyAHgFzIDOYUoA5ocgJ7kgCu6ARtPgL774ATCAgA2cKCgBu45HHIZsAGmQd5mLPxgB7KMgAUCLSCrIA1hEbItMZAHkOAK2FgAdOcYU9cAJSyK+92s0dW8AbQBdXwIiDlD3cOQAXlk4i3DefCA)?

Comment: возьму на заметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С циклом заставить ts понять тип не получится (по крайней мере, я не знаю способа): [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFswAtkG8BQyyAHgFzIDOYUoA5ocgJ7kgCu6ARtPgL774ATCAgA2cKCgBu45HHIZsAGmQd5mLPxgB7KMgAUCLSCrIA1hEbItMZAHkOAK2FgAdOcYU9cAJSyK+92s0dW8AbQBdXwIiDlD3cOQAXlk4iwSAenTkABVGAAcUAHIqGhBaZAAfZDZOaELkYH8QLTA-CmBaEDgOERQwLWQwfKKQCEk6l158IA)

```
interface Smth {
  x: string
  y: number
}

declare var a: Smth, b: Smth

for (const key of Object.keys(a) as (keyof Smth)[]) {
  b[key] = a[key] // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

Но можно использовать хак с приведением типа: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFswAtkG8BQyyAHgFzIDOYUoA5ocgJ7kgCu6ARtPgL774ATCAgA2cKCgBu45HHIZsAGmQd5mLPxgB7KMgAUCLSCrIA1hEbItMZAHkOAK2FgAdOcYU9cAJSyK+92s0dW8AbQBdXwIiDlD3cOQAXlk4iwS4fxAISW4+IA)

```
interface Smth {
  x: string
  y: number
}

declare var a: Smth, b: Smth

for (const key of Object.keys(a) as (keyof Smth)[]) {
  b[key] = a[key] as never
}
```

Ещё можно химичить через функцию, но я бы не стал потому что это лишнее нагромождение кода: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFswAtkG8BQyyAHgFzIDOYUoA5ocgJ7kgCu6ARtPgL774ATCAgA2cKCgBu45HHIZsAGmQd5mLPxisQCMMAD2IZAn0AHRgB4AKsoDSyCMUggBFZAGsIjfTGRWAfAAUQlTkNpT6rFBIYcqezMi2AJR4DCFgANrxALrIALwRUUhZXtm8mvpQyIEmIFQeXsg+yADyHABWwmAAdPEUgXApcG6B8c0KWEkZ2SkERCbmgRzKcHFeSQDc5UA)

```
interface Smth {
  x: string
  y: number
}

declare var a: Smth, b: Smth

function copy<T, K extends keyof T>(dest: T, source: T, key: K) {
  dest[key] = source[key]
}

for (const key of Object.keys(a) as (keyof Smth)[]) {
  copy(b, a, key);
}
```